# How to create Kiosk which shows a page for a number of seconds and then another

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, spring-mvc, iframe

I would like to develop a web application which should run in kiosk mode. It should have two modes for displaying information in sequences on two monitors.

Mode1 should display on monitor1 this sequence: Screen 1 (x seconds) -> Screen2 (y seconds) -> Screen 3 (x seconds) and repeat

Mode 2 should should display on monitor2 this sequence: Screen 1 (x seconds) -> Screen 3 (y seconds) and repeat

Unfortunately I have almost no idea how to implement the logic.
Maybe with iframes?

I would prefer a centralized solution.

E.g. when I go to http://localhost:8084/monitor1 it should display mode1 screen sequence without reloading page

And when I go to http://localhost:8084/monitor2 it should display mode2 screen sequence without reloading the page

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info on what exactly you need to develop. As per my assumption, you need something like this

```
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                //Your logic goes here
            }, 10)
```